# Regex matching date pattern

Tags: c#, regex, datetime

I want to match filenames with date format and **ANY extension**.
Is following regex good for this:

```
[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{4}(?:\..*)?
```

??

Above regex, although seems to work, does not return this
string in result: `"12.1.1990.txt"`
How to write regex which also includes dates like either

```
12.12.2203.bmp
or
1.11.2005.txt
or
12.1.2006.bin
?
```

Thanks. And ps. where to find further info on writing these expressions?

Comment: I use this cheat sheet to write regexes http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{4}(?:\..*)?$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/mK1tT3/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
[0-9]{2}.[0-9]**{1,2}**.[0-9]{4}(?:\..*)?
```

Comment: But be aware that the period will match any character if not escaped.

Comment: '.' will match any character but '\.' will match a period.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for this regex:

```
\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}.\d{4}(?:\.\w*)?
```

Also, I'm using some online regex tools for checking my regex, which is very handy on checking specific things (not to advertise or anything).

By this website, [FileExt](http://filext.com/faq/file_extension_information.php), DOS illegal characters in file extension are this: 
|<>\^=?/[]";* plus control characters, so changing the file extension regex to this one:
`(?:\.[^\|\<\>\\\^\=\?\/\[\]\"\;\*\.]*)?` will match valid file extensions.

The final regex would be: `\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}.\d{4}(?:\.[^\|\<\>\\\^\=\?\/\[\]\"\;\*\.]*)?`

**[Regex101](http://regex101.com/)**

Comment: Say I want user to type regex ONLY for filenames - without extension. How can I concatenate Regex for only filenames and regex which allows any file type?

Comment: @Lucaci you need to escape the dot in your regex so that it would match a literal dot.

Comment: The `(?:\..*)?` part of the regex makes it optional, that is, if your user types only a date composed of this `mm.dd.yyyy` without any file extension, this regex will match it too.

Comment: @LucaciAndrei: Be it optional. In general can you say how regex looks like which allows any file type? and be it also optional (if there is no file type it is ok). I will need to concatenate this regex with other regex. thanks

Comment: So, to answer to your first question: Yes. This regex will match any filename of the type: `mm.dd.yyyy` or `mm.dd.yyyy.[your-extension]`.
But, I cannot answer to your other question because I don't know, what you mean by _I will need to concatenate this regex with other regex_? What is the context, what are you trying to achieve?